# Angular JS - go to otherwise state without changing the URL

Tags: angularjs

Hi I have been using `stateprovider` for a long time and this time I want to implement a functionality in which without changing the url, I want to go `not found state` but not on url.

This is my code.

```
(function () {
angular.module('mean').config(aosOfferConfig);

function aosOfferConfig($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/link/404_not_found");
    $stateProvider
        .state('offers', {
            url: '/offers/packages',
            templateUrl: 'views/aosOffers/aosoffers.html',
            controller: 'offersController',
            controllerAs: 'packages'
        })
        .state('offersignup', {
            url: '/offers/signup',
            templateUrl: 'views/aosOffers/offerssignup.html',
            controller: 'offersSignupController',
            controllerAs: 'offerssignup'
        })
        .state('thankyou', {
            url: '/offers/thankyou',
            templateUrl: 'views/aosOffers/offersthankyou.html'
        });
    }
})();
```

Now in my otherwise part I am taking the user to `/link/404_not_found`. I don't want this. Instead, I want that it will remain in current url but the state should be changed. Just like github does.

How can I do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

do it this way

```
(function () {
angular.module('mean').config(aosOfferConfig);

function aosOfferConfig($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise(function ($injector, $location) {
        var state = $injector.get('$state');
        state.go('404_not_found', {}, { location: false });
         return $location.path();
    });
    $stateProvider
        .state('offers', {
            url: '/offers/packages',
            templateUrl: 'views/aosOffers/aosoffers.html',
            controller: 'offersController',
            controllerAs: 'packages'
        })
        .state('offersignup', {
            url: '/offers/signup',
            templateUrl: 'views/aosOffers/offerssignup.html',
            controller: 'offersSignupController',
            controllerAs: 'offerssignup'
        })
        .state('thankyou', {
            url: '/offers/thankyou',
            templateUrl: 'views/aosOffers/offersthankyou.html'
        })
        .state('404_not_found', {
            template: '<h1>Notfound</h1>'
        });
  }
})();
```